# Updata And delete from table

Tags: php

when i click  on delete the page get refresh but data is not deleted can you tell me what’s the problem.tell me also how should i edit the data using edit.help me out in this ... i tried my best.

this is my delete page

```
<?php
        $database = "example";
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
        $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
        $id=$_REQUEST['ID'];
            // sending query
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM my WHERE ID = '$id'")
            or die(mysql_error());      

            header("Location: main.php");
        ?>
```

this is my main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Employee</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><b><font size=20>Employee Detail</font></b></center>
    <?php
    $database = "example";
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM my";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            print "<table border='1'>";
            print "<tr>";
            print "<th>ID</th>";
            print "<th>First name</th>";
            print "<th>Last name</th>";
            print "<th>Gender</th>";
            print "<th>Address</th>";
            print "<th>Contact_no</th>";
            print "<th>Picture</th>";
            print "<th>User_name</th>";
            print "<th>Password</th>";
            print "<th>Email_id</th>";
        while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
        {

            print "<tr>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['ID']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['F_name']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['L_name']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['Gender']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['Address']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['Contact_no']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['Picture']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['U_name']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['Password']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$db_field['Email_id']."</td>";
            echo"<td> <a href ='edit.php?ID=$id'>Edit</a>";
            echo"<td> <a href ='delete.php?ID=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";
            print "</tr>";

        }
            print "</table>";

        mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
    <form>
    <a href="test1.php">
    <input type="button" value="Add">
    </a>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is my add page

```
<?php

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Sign up Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validation()
{
    if (document.login.fname.value==null || document.login.fname.value=="")
    {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        document.login.fname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if((document.login.fname.value.length<3))
    {
        alert("First name is too short");
        document.login.psw.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.login.lname.value==null || document.login.lname.value=="")
    {
        alert("Last name must be filled out");
        document.login.lname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if((document.login.lname.value.length<3))
    {
        alert("Last name is too short");
        document.login.psw.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if( document.login.select.selectedIndex==0)
    {
            alert( "Gender must be filled out" );
        document.login.select.focus();
            return false;
    }
    if (document.login.address.value==null || document.login.address.value=="")
    {
        alert("Address must be filled out");
        document.login.address.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if((document.login.address.value.length < 20))
    {
        alert(" Your address must be 20 characters");       
        document.login.address.select();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.login.contact_no.value==null || document.login.contact_no.value=="")
    {
        alert("Contact number must be filled out");
        document.login.contact_no.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(isNaN(document.login.contact_no.value))
    {
        alert("You use charecter in contact number");
        document.login.contact_no.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if((document.login.contact_no.value.length < 1) || (document.login.contact_no.value.length > 10))
    {
        alert("you enter more than 10 digit in contact");
        document.login.contact_no.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.login.picture.value==null || document.login.picture.value=="")
    {
        alert("You must select an Image or Images");
        document.login.picture.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.login.uname.value==null || document.login.uname.value=="")
    {
        alert("Login name must be filled out");
        document.login.uname.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if((document.login.psw.value.length<4))
    {
        alert("Password is too short");
        document.login.psw.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.login.psw.value==null || document.login.uname.value=="")
    {
        alert("Password must be filled out");
        document.login.psw.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var emailfilter=/^\w+[\+\.\w-]*@([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*\.([a-z]{2,4}|\d+)$/i
    var b=emailfilter.test(document.login.e_id.value);
    if(b==false)
    {
        alert("Please Enter a valid Mail ID");
        document.login.e_id.focus();
        return false;
    }

}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login" action="insert.php" onsubmit="return(validation())" method="post" enctype= multipart/form-data>
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td><select name="select">
   <option value="-1" selected>[Select option]</option>
   <option value="male">Male</option>
   <option value="female">Female</option>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><textarea name="address" col="60" row="10"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Contact no:</td>
<td><input type="number" name="contact_no"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Picture:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="picture"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>User name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="uname"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="psw"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email id:</td>
<td><input type="email" name="e_id"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my edit page

```
<?php
$database = "example";
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
$id =$_REQUEST['ID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my WHERE ID = '$id'");
$db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
        {
        die("Error: Data not found..");
        }
            $F_name=$db_field['F_name'];
            $L_name=$db_field['L_name'];
            $Gender=$db_field['Gender'];
            $Address=$db_field['Address'];
            $Contact_no=$db_field['Contact_no'];
            $Picture=$db_field['Picture'];
            $U_name=$db_field['U_name'];
            $Password=$db_field['Password'];
            $Email_id=$db_field['Email_id'];

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $fname_save = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname_save = $_POST['lname'];
    $gender_save = $_POST['select'];
    $address_save = $_POST['address'];
    $contactno_save = $_POST['contact_no'];
    $picture_save = $_POST['picture'];
    $uname_save = $_POST['u_name'];
    $password_save = $_POST['psw'];
    $emailid_save = $_POST['e_id'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE my SET F_name='$fname_save', L_name='$lname_save', Gender='$gender_save', Address='$address_save',               Contact_no='$contactno_save', Picture='$picture_save', U_name='$uname_save', Password='$password_save',                 Email_id='$emailid_save' WHERE ID = '$id'")
                or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "Saved!";

    header("Location: main.php");           
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $F_name ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $L_name ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td><select name="select" value="<?php echo $Gender ?>">
        <option value="-1" selected>[Select option]</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td><textarea name="address" col="60" row="10" value="<?php echo $Address ?>"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Contact no:</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="contact_no" value="<?php echo $Contact_no ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Picture:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="picture" value="<?php echo $Picture ?>"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>User name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $U_name ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="psw" value="<?php echo $Password ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Email id:</td>
        <td><input type="email" name="e_id" value="<?php echo $Email_id ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my database

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
     if (!$conn)
        {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected Successfully';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE my(
        ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        F_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        L_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        Gender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Contact_no INT NOT NULL,
    Picture BLOB NOT NULL,
    U_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Email_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        primary key ( ID ))";

mysql_select_db('example');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Table my created successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
?> 
echo ("<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[employees_number]\">Delete</a></td></tr>")
```

Comment: You never set `$id` in the main page, but you use it in your `echo` statements. Aren't you getting PHP warnings from that?

Comment: no i didnt get any php warning

Comment: You must not have all error reporting enabled. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script while debugging.

Comment: Unrelated: you're missing `</td>` on the `Edit` and `Delete` lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
$id = $db_field['ID'];
```

to the beginning of the `while` loop on the main page. You're using this variable in the URLs in your `echo` statements, but never setting it.